# How to sort order of map.keySet() in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap, sortedmap, keyset

```
public class MapKeyExample {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        //Initializing a Map of type HashMap
        Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<>();
        map.put(1, "One");
        map.put(3, "Three");
        map.put(5, "Five");
        map.put(7, "Seven");
        map.put(9, "Nine");
        System.out.println(map);
        s = map.keySet();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Now the output is

```
{1=One, 3=Three, 5=Five, 7=Seven, 9=Nine}
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

The expected output of s is:

```
[1, 5, 3, 9, 7]
```

Can someone show me how to modify this to Linkedhashmap or treemap? Many thanks.

Comment: Use `SortedMap` instead of `HashMap`.

Comment: Can you explain the expected output? What pattern does it follow?

Comment: @Marvin no pattern because I want to specify the order and change it to the order I want, I tried TreeMap but it gives me the natural order of integer.

Comment: @Cecilia It does not make sense to ask "can you show how to make this into the order I want" if you can't explain what is the order you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what you mean by "change it to the order I want".

However, Java provides these options:

- A [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) can be iterated over in the same order you inserted the entries in.
- `TreeMap`'s constructor allows you to provide a `Comparator`, which will define the order of the keys.

Answer (score 0):

The order of key is undefined for the most types of maps. Sorting of keys is supported in the `TreeMap`. In your case the default order (the natural order of `Integer`) will be sufficient. To produce your own order, implement corresponding comparator.

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
    public int compare(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
        ...
        // If i1 should be before i2, return -1
        // If i1 should be after i2, return 1
        // Otherwise return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want it to be natural oder, is there a way that I can specify the order and change it to the order I want, I tried TreeMap but it gives me the natural order of integer.

Comment: You can implement your own comparator and use it as argument when you create TreeMap. In this comparator implement the logic that produces the order that you need.

Comment: I'm very new to Java, do you mind showing me an example. Many thanks.

Comment: See updated answer.